# 'tuple' has no attribute. OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tuples, traceback

I am trying to pass a window over an image so I can get the average b,g,r pixel values inside the window (not really sure how to do this).

At the moment I am trying to get a window to pass over my image but on line 17 I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\bgr.py", line 17, in <module>
    pt2=(pt1.x+5,pt1.y+5)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import dateutil
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

bgr_img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg')
height, width = bgr_img.shape[:2]

#split b,g,r channels
#b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr_img)

for i in range(0,height):
  for j in range(0,width):
    pt1=(i,j)
    pt2=(pt1.x+5,pt1.y+5)
    point.append([pt1,pt2])
    cv2.rectangle(bgr_img,pt1,pt2,(255,0,0))

#cv2.imshow('image',bgr_img)          
#cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
pt1 = (i, j)  # I have added spaces per the style guide
```

assigns a new **tuple** object to the name `pt1` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)). Tuples do not, by default, have an `x` or `y` attribute. You either need to access the first and second items in the tuple by index:

```
pt2 = (pt1[0] + 5, pt1[1] + 5)  # note 0-based indexing
```

or to create a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which allows you to define attributes:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y")

pt1 = Point(i, j)
pt2 = Point(pt1.x + 5, pt1.y + 5)
```

---

That being said, as `i` and `j` are still in scope, the *easiest* thing to do would be simply:

```
pt1 = (i, j)
pt2 = (i + 5, j + 5)
```

and even if they *weren't* still in scope you could *unpack* `pt1` (whether `tuple` or `namedtuple`), and use the separate `x` and `y`:

```
x, y = pt1
pt2 = (x + 5, y + 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because pt1 is a tuple and doesn't have `x` or `y` attributes . You probably want:

```
pt2 = (pt1[0] + 5, pt1[1] + 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access plain tuples like that, you need to change

```
pt2=(pt1.x+5,pt1.y+5)
```

to

```
pt2=(pt1[0] + 5, pt1[0] + 5)
```

However, Python does have a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) which can be accessed via attributes; there's even a Point namedtuple example in the docs.

Here's a small example derived from the docs I linked to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments

print p[0] + p[1]       # indexable like the plain tuple (11, 22)

x, y = p                # unpack like a regular tuple
print x, y
print p.x + p.y         # fields also accessible by name

print repr(p)           # readable __repr__ with a name=value style
print tuple(p)
```

**output**

```
33
11 22
33
Point(x=11, y=22)
(11, 22)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an `x` attribute in `pt1`, but `pt1` is a tuple and tuple have no `x` attribute. You could either

- Write a Custom Point class
- Use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

The second solution could look like the following:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
p1 = Point(i,j)
p2 = (pt1.x+5,pt1.y+5)
```